# Explain why the system of matrices $I, A, A^2, \ldots, A^{n^2 + 1}$ is dependent

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-independence

For context, one of the homework problems given in my linear algebra classes is this:

> Given $0 \neq A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$, prove there is a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and a monic polynomial $m_A$ of degree $k$ such that $m_A(A) = 0$ and if $q \neq 0$ is a polynomial and $q(A) = 0$, then the degree of $q$ is at least $k$.

They left this as a hint:

> [Suggestion: Explain why the system of vectors $I, A, A^2, . . . , A^{n^2 + 1}$ is dependent in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$. Conclude the set $$S = \{m \in \mathbb{N}^+ : I, A, A^2, . . . , A^m\text{ is dependent}\}$$ is not empty and thus has a smallest element, say $k$. Proceed.]

I have barely gained any headway with this proof, since I'm already stuck at the first part of the hint. To show that the set of vectors $\{I, A, A^2, . . . , A^{n^2 + 1}\}$ is dependent in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, I have tried constructing the following equation
$$\alpha_0 I + \alpha_1 A + \alpha_2 A^2 + \ldots + \alpha_{n^2 + 1}A^{n^2 + 1} = 0$$
using scalars $\alpha_0, \ldots, \alpha_{n^2 + 1} \in \mathbb{C}$. However, I can't seem to find anything that would force any sort of properties from these scalars, let alone whether at least one of them is nonzero. I already know that the system of vectors $I, A, A^2, \ldots, A^m$ is not necessarily dependent or independent, but I can't find any convenient properties that arise from $m$ being set to $n^2 + 1$ that would make this set dependent. What is so special about $n^2 + 1$ in this case?

---

Also, as a final question to help guide this: proving the above would imply that $n^2 + 1 \in S$, meaning that $S$ is non-empty. However, that wouldn't make it the smallest nor the largest element in $S$, since there would have to be some other element, which I could conveniently name $k \in S$, such that $k < n^2 + 1$. However, what exactly would guarantee that such a $k$ would exist?

---

Edit: I should note that this homework was assigned within the same week that we were taught eigenvectors. I was tempted to try using what I learned this week about characteristic polynomials; however, I can't see how polynomials that take scalars as inputs would relate to polynomials that take in matrices as inputs.

Comment: Hint,. The  dimension of that vector space of matrices is just $n^2$ . What can you say about a set of $n^2+1$ elements?

Comment: @EthanBolker Why is it that the dimension of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is $n^2$?

Comment: If there is a polynomial with $q(A) = 0$, then there is a polynomial, say $p$, of least degree such that $p(A) = 0$. If you like this is because the natural numbers are well-ordered.

Comment: @Mailbox don't overthink it. How many entries are there in an $n \times n$ matrix? Can you exhibit a basis?

Comment: See @CharlesHudgins comment.

Comment: @EthanBolker Ahh, I see what you mean by your hint! We cannot exhibit a basis from a set of $n^2 + 1$ vectors, so the system of vectors in question is not a basis; that means that the system is either dependent or (inclusive) not spanning. If I'm not mistaken, an arbitrary matrix from $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ could be constructed from a linear combination of matrices from this set, so it is indeed spanning, so that would mean by elimination that it must be dependent! Is this correct?

Comment: @Mailbox. No, that is not what I meant. Exhibit the simplest basis of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ you can think of. How many vectors does it contain?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins It would contain $n^2$ vectors, wouldn't it? Also, did I say something incorrect in my previous comment?

Comment: Perhaps it might have been better to ask why **any** collection of matrices $M_1,...,M_{n^2+1}$ is linearly dependent?

Comment: @Mailbox It might not span (in fact you will prove soon that it doesn't) but it surely isn't independent since there are more vectors there than the dimension of the space.

Comment: Mailbox, please tell us a basis for the square 2 by 2 matrices.  Let me word it this way: first  tell us four matrices that add up to $$ \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
a & b \\ 
c & d \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$